# AH00326: Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting

Tags: java, apache

I am having java application it is running on `apache 2.4`. There are some configuration settings are done in apache. But my application suddenly no working after started service.

I also have enabled httpd-mpm.

`<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers          5
    MaxSpareServers         10
    MaxRequestWorkers      150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>`

`<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit             40
    StartServers             2
    MaxClients             1000
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads         75 
    ThreadsPerChild         250
    MaxRequestWorkers      1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>`

`<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    ThreadStackSize      65536
    StartThreads           250
    MinSpareThreads         25
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    MaxThreads            1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>`

`<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        1000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   100
</IfModule>`

I checked apache error log:

```
AH00326: Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting
```

I guess there are some configuration changes that I need to do. But not getting any idea.

Could you please help me. I am searching for solution from last couple of days.

`My apache 2.4 running under windows 2012.`

Comment: you got the solution for this question? If yes can you please post your answer on this question

Answer (score 2):

If Windows server, increase the **ThreadsPerChild** in **mpm_winnt_module** to **1920** (default ThreadLimit for mpm_winnt) and then restart the Apache service.

Answer (score 0):

I faced someone struggle with this problem. This is what I did to solve it.
OS: Windows

conf/httpd.conf:
uncomment the following line

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
```

conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf:
Look for the mpm_winnt_module section. Increase the ThreadsPerChild to 1920

```
# WinNT MPM
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild        1920
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```